# How to check if class exist using only css

Tags: css, dom, css-selectors

I need to change a tag on my html if another tag on my dom is **missing** a class, I need to check it with out using JS or Jquery, can I do that?

Example:

```
<a class="collapsed">MY TEXT HERE IS RED</a>
```

after clicking on this tag the class - > collapsed disappear and I need my text to change to green. the only change in my code is the collapsed been disappeared so according to that I need to change my text color
I need the hasClass function in css...

Comment: can you be more specific, give us an example of what you want before getting a bunch of downvotes

Comment: @TemaniAfif ok thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply use `:not()` selector like this :

```css
a:not(.collapsed) {
  color: green;
}

a.other {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a class="collapsed">MY TEXT HERE IS RED</a>
<a>MY TEXT HERE IS green</a>
<a class="other">MY TEXT HERE IS RED</a>
```